# How can I look up for specific package in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I can look up for resource:

```
CTRL+Shift+R
```

or for type:

```
CTRL+Shift+T
```

but what if all I know is the package name? What shortcut can help me to look up for this package? Failed to find anything meaningful on [shortcuts list](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no default shortcut for that. You have to create a new one. Go to Window > Preferences. In General > Keys you have all the commands, use the filter text to find the command "Go to a package" and add a "binding" for this. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried it but after applying the shortcut it does not work. I am using Helios. Is restart required?

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for opening a type should work.  You mentioned that in your question, so maybe I'm misunderstanding.  If you search for a type:

```
CTRL+Shift+T
```

You should be able to type in the package name and get a list of all the types in that package that are in your workspace.

Comment: I checked on Helios SR2 and it seems to work.  Are you wanting to see all the types within that package or a list of packages?  If you're looking for a list of packages instead of types, you could use `Ctrl+H` to open the search dialogue and then do a Java Search for packages.  Then once you find the package you want hit `F4` for the type hierarchy.